# ServiceStack.Text Disposes Input Stream

Tags: servicestack-text

When deserializing data from a stream ServiceStack.Text closes the input stream. Since there is no issue tracker at Github and their web site refers to SO I post the question here.
A call to

```
 JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromStream<T>(stream);
```

will dispose the input stream which is in my opinion an error since there might be other data following which is only prefixed with an object. No other serializer I am aware of behaves this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest [v5.1.1 of ServiceStack.Text on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget) shouldn't auto close streams anymore.

Also ServiceStack.Text has been rewritten to use .NET's new `ReadOnlySpan<char>` which can be accessed directly with:

```
ReadOnlySpan<char> jsonSpan = json.AsSpan();
var dto = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromSpan<T>(jsonSpan);
```

There's also a new API for reading from streams asynchronously:

```
var dto = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromStreamAsync<T>(stream);
```